# Tamil fonts not properly rendering Illustrator CC

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have this in MS Word (which I copied from google transliterator)

[image]

And when I paste it in illustrator, it get

[image]

I could paste the same anywhere else, such as Notepad, Web, and many other apps and get it perfectly rendered:

[image]

I searched in google and got to know about the language options

[image]

but I changed those options and found no difference except that I get a few extra options **Insert Aki (Left)**, **Insert Aki (Right)** and **Tsume**, and playing with those options is not helping...!

And I have tried with multiple fonts: the ones that only support Tamil such as `Akarathi` and dual encoded fonts like `Nirmala UI`, `SaiIndira`, etc.,

> **I get problems only when pasted inside Illustrator**

How do I get them rendered properly?

**EDIT**: I have also tried as discussed in [Adobe Forums](https://forums.adobe.com/message/5651711#5651711). Converted to PDF and opened it in illustrator. And many chars get converted to lines (expanded and not editable)...!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit > Preferences > Type > Choose Text Engine Options
[image]

Thanks to **Photoshop**: the information "Changes will take effect" was not given in Illustrator, I restarted Illustrator with **Show Indic Options** ticked and everything worked like charm.

Note: If you save a document with old distorted tamil texts and open it again after changing the options, it will be of no use. You would need to replace the text copying the original text.

Answer (score 1):

Same Problem occurred for me in Illustrator:

[image]

To rectify it change the Text engine first:

*Edit* > *Preferences* > *Type* > *Language options* > Select *Show Indic options*

[image]

Paste the content now, if you are still facing the same problem:

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to open Character Panel. Change the language in the bottom, paste the text now. Try different languages until your text looks correct.

[image]

Now, the corrected text

[image]

Answer (score -4):

we can also use NHM converter for convert encodings.like unicode to TAB,tace and etc..

Comment: Is this an answer to the question? What is NHM? Please edit to clarify what exactly you mean and how it answers the question.